# Ambiguous function call in msvc and clang but not in gcc

Tags: c++, constructor

I wonder which compiler is compliant with the standard, i use the following code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>


class AbstractBase
{
public:
    virtual ~AbstractBase() {};
    virtual std::string get_name() = 0;
    virtual int get_number() = 0;
};

class BaseImpl : public AbstractBase
{
public:
    BaseImpl() = delete;             //(a)
    //BaseImpl(BaseImpl&) = delete;  //(b)
    BaseImpl(const std::vector<std::string>& name_) : name(name_) {}
    std::string get_name() override {return name.empty() ? std::string("empty") : name.front();}
private:
    std::vector<std::string> name{};
};

class impl : public BaseImpl
{
public:
    impl() : BaseImpl({}) {} 
    int get_number() override {return 42;} 
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<AbstractBase> intance = std::make_unique<impl>();
    std::cout << intance->get_name() << " " << intance->get_number() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

msvc and clang produce a compiler error while gcc is fine with this code. Link to godbold

https://godbolt.org/z/ETYGn5T1h

If one explicit delete the copy ctor of BaseImpl (uncomment (b)) all three compiler are fine. Also if one do not explicitly delete (a) the standard ctor (then no standard ctor is generated because there is an user defined ctor), all compilers are fine.

Apparently clang and msvc believe that by `: BaseImpl({})` they can either call the user defined ctor, or indirectly via the default ctor the implicit copy ctor. However, since the default ctor is deleted, this ambiguity should not exist at all. However, by explicitly deleting the default ctor, the compilers seem to first assume that a default ctor exists for BaseImpl and generate an error before checking whether it is deleted.

I wonder now if this behavior is standard compliant.

Edit: I'm attaching the compiler output for the case that one don't want to or can't click on the link to the compiler explorer:
[image: screenshot of compiler output]

Comment: please include all important information in the question (the compilers error message). Also rather than describing what has to be modified on code to get some other error or no error it is always better to post the code with the modifications

Comment: not sure but I think you misunderstand that `=delete` does not cause the function to be ignored completely. Overload resolution happens first https://godbolt.org/z/6nhvc368d

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
yes that makes sense. 
But here the compiler sees the deleted standard constructor and says, okay there is a way to convert {} implicitly to baseimpl, and i think he should realize that this way is not valid due to the delete, before he throws an error due ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang and MSVC are correct, and gcc has a bug.

Defining a function as deleted is not the same as not declaring the function.

Except for move constructors, move assignment functions, and some cases of inherited constructors (see [[over.match.funcs]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.funcs#8)), a deleted function is considered to exist for purposes of overload resolution. Nothing else in section [over] treats a deleted function specially. And we have [[over.best.ics]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.best.ics#2), emphasis mine:

> Implicit conversion sequences are concerned only with the type, cv-qualification, and value category of the argument and how these are converted to match the corresponding properties of the parameter. [ *Note:* Other properties, such as the lifetime, storage class, alignment, accessibility of the argument, whether the argument is a bit-field, and **whether a function is deleted**, are **ignored**. So, although an implicit conversion sequence can be defined for a given argument-parameter pair, the conversion from the argument to the parameter might still be ill-formed in the final analysis. — *end note* ]

So within `impl() : BaseImpl({}) {}`, the `BaseImpl` initializer uses overload resolution to select the `BaseImpl` constructor used to initialize the base class subobject. The candidates are all the constructors of `BaseImpl`: the intended `BaseImpl(const std::vector<std::string>&)`, the deleted `BaseImpl()`, the implicitly declared copy constructor `BaseImpl(const BaseImpl&)`, and the implicitly declared (and not deleted) move constructor `BaseImpl(BaseImpl&&)`. At this point, `BaseImpl()` is not viable since the initializer has one argument. The vector constructor is viable since there is a constructor `vector(std::initializer_list<std::string>)` which is not explicit and can convert the `{}` argument to the vector type. The copy and move constructors *are* also viable since the `BaseImpl()` constructor is declared, and is not explicit, and "can" convert the `{}` argument to type `BaseImpl`. So overload resolution is ambiguous, even though some of the implicit conversion sequences use a deleted function.

When the `BaseImpl() = delete;` declaration is not present, `BaseImpl` simply doesn't have any default constructor, since the `BaseImpl(const std::vector<std::string>&)` declaration prevents implicit declaration of a default constructor. So there is no implicit conversion sequence for `{}` to `BaseImpl`, and the copy and move constructors of `BaseImpl` are not viable for the initialization `BaseImpl({})`. The vector constructor is the only viable function.

When you declare `BaseImpl(BaseImpl&)`, deleted or not, this is considered a copy constructor (despite missing the usual `const`), so it prevents the implicit declarations of the copy constructor and move constructor. But this copy constructor is not viable for `BaseImpl({})`, since the reference to non-const type can't bind to the rvalue temporary `BaseImpl` object involved in using `BaseImpl()` (see [[over.ics.ref]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.ics.ref#3)). So only the intended vector constructor is viable.

Comment: So for the selection of the overloaded function it doesn't matter if the conversion sequence is i'll formed or not, only that it exists counts? Good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## WIP marker

A comment by @aschepler has thrown the conclusion in doubt. See there for details or to pitch in if you're a language lawyer. I'll have a closer look tonight, then update this answer.

## TL;DR

GCC is correct in a quite non-obvious way.

## What is happening

The clang error message seems pretty clear:

```
<source>:28:14: error: call to constructor of 'BaseImpl' is ambiguous
    impl() : BaseImpl({}) {}
             ^        ~~
<source>:14:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor)
class BaseImpl : public AbstractBase
      ^
<source>:14:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor)
<source>:19:5: note: candidate constructor
    BaseImpl(const std::vector<std::string>& name_) : name(name_) {}
    ^
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

There are three constructors that are available for the `BaseImpl({})` call -- the generated copy and move constructors, and the vector constructor. Clang does not know which of these to choose.

MSVCs error is a bit less straightforward:

```
x64 msvc v19.latest (Editor #1)

x64 msvc v19.latest
x64 msvc v19.latest
/std:c++20
123
<Compilation failed>

# For more information see the output window
x64 msvc v19.latest - 2681ms
Output of x64 msvc v19.latest (Compiler #1)
example.cpp
<source>(28): error C2259: 'BaseImpl': cannot instantiate abstract class
<source>(14): note: see declaration of 'BaseImpl'
<source>(28): note: due to following members:
<source>(28): note: 'int AbstractBase::get_number(void)': is abstract
<source>(11): note: see declaration of 'AbstractBase::get_number'
Compiler returned: 2
```

What happens here is that MSVC attempts to call the copy or move constructor, that for this it attempts to create a temporary of type `BaseImpl` from the initializer `{}`, and that this fails because `BaseImpl` is abstract before it fails because the default constructor is deleted (so you don't get an error message about that).

GCC does not consider the copy and move ctors even if they are explicitly added and so just constructs a vector and compiles fine.

## What should happen

Let's dive into the standard. In particular, let's have a look at [dcl.init.general]. I'll omit non-matching parts of the standard language and denote that with (...).

First note that according to [dcl.init.general] (15)

> 15 The initialization that occurs
>
> (15.1) — for an initializer that is a parenthesized expression-list or a braced-init-list,
>
> (...)
>
> is called direct-initialization.

There follows in [dcl.init.general] (16) a long list of conditions for what happens in initialization. The relevant here is (16.6)

> (16.6) — Otherwise, if the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
> (...)
>
> (16.6.2) — Otherwise, if the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated (12.4.2.4), and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (12.4). Then:
>
> (16.6.2.1) — If overload resolution is successful, the selected constructor is called to initialize the object, with the initializer expression or expression-list as its argument(s).
>
> (...)
>
> (16.6.2.3) — Otherwise, the initialization is ill-formed.

What this boils down to is: we look for all applicable constructors and attempt to choose a correct one. If that works, we use it, otherwise it's an error.

So let's take a look at overload resolution in [over.match.ctor]. Here it states that

> 1 When objects of class type are direct-initialized (9.4), (...), overload resolution selects the constructor. For direct-initialization or default-initialization that is not in the context of copy-initialization, the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class of the object being initialized. (...). The argument list is the expression-list or assignment-expression of the initializer.

So our set of candidate functions are the generated copy and move ctors as well as the vector ctor. Next step is checking which of these are viable according to [over.match.viable]. This means first checking that the number of arguments in the call fits the candidate functions (true for all candidates) and then that

> 4 Third, for F to be a viable function, there shall exist for each argument an implicit conversion sequence (12.4.4.2) that converts that argument to the corresponding parameter of F. If the parameter has reference type, the implicit conversion sequence includes the operation of binding the reference, and the fact that an lvalue reference to non-const cannot be bound to an rvalue and that an rvalue reference cannot be bound to an lvalue can affect the viability of the function (see 12.4.4.2.5).

An implicit conversion sequence is, according to [over.best.ics.general],

> 3 A well-formed implicit conversion sequence is one of the following forms: >
> (3.1) — a standard conversion sequence (12.4.4.2.2),
>
> (3.2) — a user-defined conversion sequence (12.4.4.2.3), or
>
> (3.3) — an ellipsis conversion sequence (12.4.4.2.4).

where a standard conversion sequence is chiefly concerned with stuff like int to long, lvalue to rvalue, ref to const ref etc. We're interested in user-defined conversion sequences here, which are

> 1 A user-defined conversion sequence consists of an initial standard conversion sequence followed by a user- defined conversion (11.4.8) followed by a second standard conversion sequence. If the user-defined conversion is specified by a constructor (11.4.8.2), the initial standard conversion sequence converts the source type to the type of the first parameter of that constructor. (...)
>
> 2 The second standard conversion sequence converts the result of the user-defined conversion to the target type for the sequence; any reference binding is included in the second standard conversion sequence. (...).
>
> (...)

There is quite definitely a user-defined conversion sequence from `{}` to `std::vector<std::string>`. Because `BaseImpl`'s default constructor is deleted, there is *not* a user-defined conversion sequence from `{}` to `BaseImpl`; this would require two user-defined conversions: one to `std::vector<std::string>` and another to `BaseImpl`.

So of the three candidate constructors, only the `std::vector<std::string>` constructor is viable and eligible for overload resolution and should be chosen. GCC does this, and unless I made an error in my analysis, MSVC and clang have a bug.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful and is in line with what I suspected, But suspecting is not knowing.
I suspect that msvc and clang mistakenly check if you can implicitly convert {} to basimpl when checking the copy ctor, assume this possibility via the default constructor, and don't check in time if that is deleted. 
 
I find it interesting that if I don't delete it explicitly in the first place, this error doesn't occur. 
https://godbolt.org/z/9qTdh36Kq
It seems that it is only considered to be present after the explicit deletion, without the deletion it is not exited in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure about "because `BaseImpl`'s default constructor is deleted, there is not a user-defined conversion sequence from `{}` to `BaseImpl`". Normally deleted declarations are visible to overload resolution, and can be the selected overload even if other non-deleted viable functions exist.

Comment: "There is quite definitely a user-defined conversion sequence from `{}` to `std::vector<std::string>`" Why is that? Conversions are applied to objects, and `{}` is not an object.

Comment: If there were no user-defined conversion sequence from `{}` to `std::vector<std::string>`, no function accepting a `std::vector<std::string>` could be called with `{}` as a parameter; this too requires an implicit conversion sequence. The point about deleted functions being visible for overload resolution is an interesting one; it had not occurred to me that a sequence would not be broken by a deleted function. The more I think about it, the more it makes sense to me, though. Hmm. I'll revisit this in the evening; until then I'll mark the conclusion as in-doubt and refer people to the comments